# Initialization in Libgdx?

Tags: java, object, libgdx, initialization

In the create method i am trying to initialize a position reference to viewport
but its not working and after using LOG i came to know that my position at x is zero

I am creating object of Player in playscreen here

```
public class PlayScreen extends ScreenAdapter {
    public static final String TAG =PlayScreen.class.getName();

         ExtendViewport viewport;
         Player player;


    @Override
    public void show() {
        //viewport size 512X512
        viewport=new ExtendViewport(Constants.WORLD_SIZE,Constants.WORLD_SIZE);

        player=new Player(viewport);    

}
```

and my player class where i am calculating the position reference to viewport

```
public class Player{
    Vector2 position;

    Viewport viewport;

    public Player(Viewport viewport)
    {
        this.viewport=viewport;
        position= new    Vector2(viewport.getCamera().position.x+viewport.getWorldWidth(),y);

    }
```

while the Viewport width is about 620,so according to calculation position.x must be greater than 620,but its 0 on log.Little bit confuse on how things initialized in on create?

Comment: need some more code ??

Comment: what is viewport variable ??

Comment: Where are you setting this vector? in show(), in the constructor or somewhere else?

Comment: Sounds like you're doing the calculation before the viewport is updated in the `resize` method.

Comment: yes i am initializing from show method,where it calculate. so there is no parameter associated with viewport untill resize is called., So i can't create object in show method, if i am  using viewport as calculation parameter.

Comment: actually,i used viewport.worldWidth for calculation previously in show method,and it worked fine

Comment: You should create your objects in `create()`. Just update them in `resize()`.